# Rdlc reporting issue expresssion in report not running

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I created 4 reports all of them worked i have an expression in all to count rows:

```
=IIF(Fields!Logged30Days.Value = "yes", Count(Fields!Logged30Days.Value),0)
```

But today i see on all this is returning 0 when there are rows in the report it suddenly stops working how to fix this and why is it happening?

```
UPDATE
```

Now i see the expression are not working on any report, even on the earlier backup versions where they worked!

And if i do this it works but for all the rows just to show expression works ! but its not working as it did before above.How do i change this below to get desired result.

```
=IIF(Fields!Logged30Days.Value = "yes", count(Fields!Logged30Days.Value),count(Fields!Logged30Days.Value))
```

Comment: Is this expression in a Table or Group header row?

Comment: @IanPreston its on empty space no row no table , but i have expression everywhere inside groups! on group header on blank just dragged and drop to display values etc... But they wont work now i am adding them using parameters so calculate everything on start and its working. But for one with charts i need the expression to make the chart columns i cannot add parameters!

Comment: @IanPreston the weird thing is its was all working one yesterday .Suddenly all expression on any report wont work even on my client pc which has no link to mine where it all worked.

Comment: I would check all the values of `Logged30Days`. What you're effectively doing above is checking the first value of `Logged30Days` in whatever Scope the expression is... If that is not *yes*, even if there are *yes* values elsewhere in the Scope's data, you'll get 0 in the expression.

Comment: @IanPreston the expression is on value field inside a chart so its bound to automatically do it for all the rows so the above does not apply here i think.

Comment: @IanPreston  you are rite but it works when in condition = is the first row of the record example if first rows has YES it works all they way , If first row has no it doesnot. Similarly if first rows has no and i put in condition not equal to yes it works not sure what it is and why acting like this ! What is the term should i use?

Comment: So just to confirm, is it the case that if ANY values of `Logged30Days` = *yes* in the current Scope, you want to display `count(Fields!Logged30Days.Value)`, else 0? Or is there some other logic here?

Comment: @IanPreston yes thats it. So simply at the end of the report i want to count all rows in the report and if yes add +1 to the counter if no add 0 to conter and the end show counter above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems like all you need is the following expression:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged30Days.Value = "yes", 1, 0)
```

All this is doing is counting the rows with a *yes* value for `Logged30Days`; it the value is not *yes* it's just ignored for the count.

In your case,

```
=IIF(Fields!Logged30Days.Value = "yes", Count(Fields!Logged30Days.Value),0)
```

is the same as:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Logged30Days.Value) = "yes", Count(Fields!Logged30Days.Value),0)
```

i.e. when there is more than one row in the Scope but no aggregate specified it will just take the first row. So the expression was determined by the first row's value only. Also, when the first value was *yes* the `Count` would count all rows, even those where the value was not *yes*, which was also not quite what you were after either, I think.

Comment: So simple :| and perfect.... Just curious mine worked when first row was YES it did the count  if first row was no it died what was the issue.

Comment: Added a bit more detail, hope it helps.